# why the color of the :link don't show?

Tags: css

I set the a's style to be red, but color of :link doesn't work, why?
I don't click the link, the color of it should be red, but it shows green for me.

```css
a:link{
  color: red;
}
a:visited{
  color: green;
}
a:hover{
  color: blue;
}
a:active{
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
```

My result:

[image: green text]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions.

Comment: Maybe because you've visited it before?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you might want to read up on the rules/ guides before asking a question (been there).

However, to answer your question you do not need to use the `:link` when styling an `a` tag, just simply style is as such:

```
a {
 color: red;
}
```

Here is a working example of what you're after; https://codepen.io/MartynMc/pen/KqYrWY